# Firebase error. Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I'm doing a project with Firebase but when I sync gradle in the project, everything ok but the moment I try to run it many class duplication errors appear
This happens when I add implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1',
it works perfect if I remove 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1' but I need to use some admin functions.
Any solution, please?

**GRADLE/app**

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.7.4'
    implementation 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.7.4'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'


    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1'




    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force("com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.6.3")
        }
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**ERRORS**

```
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-common-19.4.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.4.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseAppLifecycleListener found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-common-19.4.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.4.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseException found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.1.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-common-19.4.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.4.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-common-19.4.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.4.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-common-19.4.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:19.4.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.ActionCodeSettings found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-20.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.ActionCodeSettings$Builder found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-20.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-20.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-interop-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-interop:19.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.auth.UserInfo found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-auth-20.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:20.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot$1$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$2 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$3 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$4 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$5 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference$CompletionListener found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Exclude found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.GenericTypeIndicator found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.InternalHelpers found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.MutableData found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.MutableData$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.MutableData$1$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.MutableData$2 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.MutableData$2$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.OnDisconnect found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.OnDisconnect$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.OnDisconnect$2 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.OnDisconnect$3 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.PropertyName found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Query found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Query$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Query$2 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Query$3 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Query$4 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ThrowOnExtraProperties found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Transaction found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Transaction$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Transaction$Handler found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.Transaction$Result found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.annotations.NotNull found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.annotations.Nullable found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.ArraySortedMap found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.ArraySortedMap$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.ImmutableSortedMap found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.ImmutableSortedMap$Builder found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.ImmutableSortedMap$Builder$KeyTranslator found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.ImmutableSortedMapIterator found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.ImmutableSortedSet found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.ImmutableSortedSet$WrappedEntryIterator found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.LLRBBlackValueNode found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.LLRBEmptyNode found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.LLRBNode found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.LLRBNode$Color found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.LLRBNode$NodeVisitor found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.LLRBNode$ShortCircuitingNodeVisitor found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.LLRBRedValueNode found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.LLRBValueNode found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.RBTreeSortedMap found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.RBTreeSortedMap$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.RBTreeSortedMap$Builder found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.RBTreeSortedMap$Builder$Base1_2 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.RBTreeSortedMap$Builder$Base1_2$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.RBTreeSortedMap$Builder$BooleanChunk found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.collection.StandardComparator found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-collection-17.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database-collection:17.0.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.CompoundHash found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection$Delegate found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection$DisconnectReason found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.Connection$State found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.ConnectionAuthTokenProvider found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.ConnectionAuthTokenProvider$GetTokenCallback found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.ConnectionContext found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.ConnectionUtils found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.Constants found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.HostInfo found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.ListenHashProvider found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnection found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnection$Delegate found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$1$1 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$2 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$3 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$4 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$5 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$6 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$7 found in modules jetified-firebase-admin-7.0.1.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:7.0.1) and jetified-firebase-database-19.5.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.5.1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `com.google.firebase:firebase-admin` from your app.  It's not meant for use in Android apps - it's for backend code only.  Whatever you're trying to do with it is almost certainly not supported.

Comment: So there is no way to have an app level user control...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  firebase-admin is for priviledged access to a Firebase project.  It would be a massive security hole to allow user-controlled software that kind of access.

Comment: @DougStevenson for my case, I want to get rid off the error msg in Firebase-> Project Settings -> Service Accounts -> Database Secrets (msg is: Database secrets are currently deprecated and use a legacy Firebase token generator. Update your source code with the Firebase Admin SDK... Learn more). My app is android, so should I ignore that error msg?

Answer (score 0):

**Solid Answer:**
you cant add firebase admin sdk into the android studio java/kotlin app, it will give 3 pages of duplicate classes error.

The proper way are go with the backend, create a api to handle user with your android app

**Hacky Answer:**
You can go without Firebase SDK (Crashlytics, Storage, FireStore, Analytics...,) then you can able to implement the admin dependency. even not recommended to use with proto data store. it will give huge list of duplicate classes.

I used a tricky method and get it done.

it's very simple

- Create new project via android studio
- include admin sdk
- create asset and place the json
- load it with below code

```
val serviceAccount = context.assets.open("admin-configuration.json")
                val options: FirebaseOptions = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                  .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .build()
                val nativeDevpsApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
                val defaultAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance(nativeDevpsApp)
```

happy coding! <3